# What was given in Har Sinai?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, kabbalat-hatorah, har-sinai

It's common knowledge that Moshe received the Torah in Har Sinai. He wrote the Pentateuch directly dictated from Hashem there and brought it down. But we also learn that he came down with the Ten Commandments in the Luchot HaBrit (Stone Tablets) and that he broke them the first time when he saw the golden calf.

Did Moshe Rabbeinu came down the first time with the Pentateuch AND the Stone Tablets (which were broken) and a second time with just the Stone Tablets? How was the order and how could he carry all of this?

***Side Note***: I know the Torah Moshe brought down wasn't the complete Torah we read today; Yehoshua continued and finished it. The question marked as a duplicate does not answer my questions.

Comment: It should be noted that the written torah was given in the mishkan in two stages. The source text from the torah is that "G-d spoke from between the cherubim." The talmud goes into more detail, but I can't find the cite on my phone.

Comment: I know it wasn't the complete Torah we read today, Yehoshua finished it. I'm referring to the part Moshe wrote.

Comment: As I recall, Moshe was taught the whole set of Halacha while up on Sinai for the forty days and nights. The written torah was dictated and he wrote it in its final form just before he died.

Comment: Here is a link to an Aish article that goes into significant detail. http://www.aish.com/jl/b/bb/48936097.html